# Show / Hide tabular data on demand via js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table, hide

I seem to have a bit of an issue and maybe someone can help me out.

What I would like to do with this code is to hide the table row/column if there is no data that is being pulled from the DB. I was able to somewhat do this with the following code :

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">

  <table class="tableizer-table">
    <tr>
      <td class="first-row" colspan="2"># Of Items in Package: <?php echo $_product->getItemsInPackage(); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="second-row">Size Scale</td>
      <td class="second-row">Quantity</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_size_1') ?></td>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_quantity_one') ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_size_2')  ?></td>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_quantity_two') ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_size_3')  ?></td>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_quantity_three') ?></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_size_4')  ?></td>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_quantity_four') ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_size_5')  ?></td>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_quantity_five') ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_size_6')  ?></td>
      <td class="cell" style="empty-cells:hide; border-collapse: separate;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('bundle_quantity_six') ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Basically, bundle_size_5 & bundle_size_6 (and others) - may or may not exist and I need to hide those rows/columns. But I would also like to stylize it with CSS (the border example) and noticed that even though they're hidden, the reserved space is still there and the border goes around it.

Is there a way via js or jQuery to completely hide those rows/columns unless data is there?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$('.tableizer-table tr').each(function() {
   var t =  $(this).find('td');
    if ( t.text() === '' ) {
     t.css('borderLeft','0px'); //or border-left
     t.hide();
    }  
  });
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GjWGp/5/)

[Manual](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for property `borderLeft`, and not 'border'.

Comment: Here's an approach with less code... be careful trying it, may not work for all cases: http://jsfiddle.net/Ccwpm/

Comment: Thank you for the code , but it seems to not be working for me. This is what it does when I apply it to my code (image) : http://imgur.com/VCOGOHI - the gray border is still going around the white space where the cells are hiding :( - thanks again for your help.